# Data SE / SQL Query - Return all columns, not just most recent selected when storing in variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a query on Data SE, and so far I have the following code:

```
DECLARE @ParentId int;
DECLARE @AnswerId int;

SELECT @ParentId = ParentId, @AnswerId = Id FROM Posts
WHERE
  OwnerUserId = 5620297
 AND
  PostTypeId = 2;

SELECT * FROM Posts
WHERE
  Id = @ParentId
 AND
  AcceptedAnswerId != @AnswerId
```

Basically, the query should return a question that has an answer of mine, however someone else's answer has been accepted.

The query above works, however, it only checks the most recent question / answer. How can I change this to check and return every question I answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `JOIN` your tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM Posts P1
INNER JOIN (SELECT ParentId, Id 
            FROM Posts
            WHERE OwnerUserId = 5620297
            AND PostTypeId = 2) P2
    ON P1.Id = P2.ParentId
    AND P1.AcceptedAnswerId <> P2.Id;
```